# Google Search Console search analytics reports impression spikes every Friday that don't lead to additional click. Why?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, impressions

Every Friday the Impressions Spikes up abnormally , but the Click rate still the same or even fewer than the previous day,
I have checked all Crons job , the server , Weekly Keywords Checker
(like Semrush) and google analytics but nothing seems strange each Friday.
We was using Semrush before, and we stop it and blocked their bots, to see if they causing the problem with no chance.
website: wordpress platform
main plugins may causing the problem: yoast

the website is about Inventory System and Asset Tracking.
https://asapsystems.com/

the queries and pages on spikes day and the previous day:

[image]

[image]

so it seems like the "warehouse" keyword is the main reason of impressions, but in all other days it doesn't have that high impressions.

for the devices and country

US -  10,653 - 3,209

Desktop - 15,794 - 8,747

and for the Search Appearance is the same for spikes and other days.

[image]

Any suggestions or explanation . and how can I stop this impressions peak?

Comment: There is no way to answer this from the given information.  What subject is your site about?   What keywords are involved in the spike?  Do you see a corresponding spike in traffic to your site?

Comment: Why are you checking things on your server when you see a spike in Google searches that show your site in the search results?

Comment: Hi , I have edited the post.
the traffics are normal.
checked the crons job on the server and the traffic from the panel.

Comment: Are Fridays typically the day that inventories are done in warehouses?

Comment: I don't think it's related to the problem

Comment: What average position is Google Search Console reporting for your site for those keywords?

Comment: warehouse inventory management : 28 at friday -  and -  36  for normal days
warehouse inventory management software: 26.5 friday - 29 normal days

Answer (score 2):

It seems to reflect a real pattern in user behaviour in your market. If you look at Google Trends for your search terms, you'll see similar weekly spikes. It's even early, and extended, over the US Thanksgiving weekend.

[image]

Presumably you either work for this company or they're your client; you should be better placed to have some insight that would explain this behaviour.

Comment: I think they are confused by what "impressions" actually means.   If they knew more, they wouldn't be checking their cron jobs and their site's bot hits.

Comment: yes I just checked google trends and yes spikes happened every Friday too. can't it be keywords checker, which anyone can run it weekly or something similar ?
@StephenOstermiller I checked the Crons job on the website because it may a plugin or a script that can check keywords weekly, and for the bots , was only to check if there is anything not normal.

Comment: I just need a Logical explanation of what causing this problem , maybe one of the competitor running keywords weekly checker?
and it may be from our side. using a platforms like SEMrush and SEObility.
the hardest part it's something externally , so I can't define or know the problem exactly .
@StephenOstermiller impressions simply mean that affected pages are showing on google result even if no clicks happens , that why it's something externally and cannot be tracked for me

Comment: It looks to me like actual users searching more on Fridays because that is the day that they usually have to do inventories.  Your average positions are so low, that you just don't see many clicks from all this extra activity.

Comment: yes it could be, but 1 year ago it was happening every Wednesday  for 2 month then it goes to friday

Comment: It is possible that somebody has a keyword checker running every Friday.  They'd have to be checking 10,000+ keywords for which you are ranking.   Google is usually pretty good about shutting down such large volume automated searches.

Comment: that's very logical answer, any suggestions what i should do or how can I identify who running this keywords checker?